# Filtering on labels in Docker API not working (possible bug?)

Tags: rest, api, docker, containers

I'm using the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/) to get info on containers in JSON format. Basically, I want to do a filter based on label values, but it is not working (just returns all containers). This filter query DOES work if you just use the command line docker, i.e.:

docker ps -a -f label=owner=fred -f label=speccont=true

However, if I try to do the equivalent filter query using the API, it just returns ALL containers (no filtering done), i.e.:

curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json?all=true&filters={"label":["speccont=true","owner=fred"]}

Note that I do uri escape the filters param when I execute it, but am just showing it here unescaped for readability.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or does this seem to be a bug in the Docker API? Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for filtering containers by *label* as of [Docker API v1.41](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerList) is

```
curl -s -G -X GET --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json" \
--data 'all=true' \
--data-urlencode 'filters={"label":["speccont=true","owner=fred"]}'
```

Note the automatic URL encoding as mentioned in this [stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86737/80213).

Answer (score -1):

I felt there was a bug with API too. But turns out there is none. I am on API version 1.30.

I get desired results with this call:

`curl  -sS localhost:4243/containers/json?filters=%7B%22ancestor%22%3A%20%5B%222bab985010c3%22%5D%7D`

I got the url escaped string using used above with:

`python -c 'import urllib; print urllib.quote("""{"ancestor": ["2bab985010c3"]}""")'`

Comment: Where did you get "ancestor" from? It's not listed as an available filter.